# Why the ugly .". in my unpublished citations?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, punctuation

Just as a preamble, I use MikTex 2.8, the latest TeXworks for Windows, the natbib package, JabRef to manage my citations, and the pdfLatex option in TeXworks for compilation.

When I cite an unpublished paper (or an "electronic" one), I get one more period than I'm looking for in the compiled output, and I don't understand why.

Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}
\usepackage[pdftex,
        urlcolor=rltblue,       % \href{...}{...} external (URL)
        filecolor=rltgreen,     % \href{...} local file
        linkcolor=rltred,       % \ref{...} and \pageref{...}
        citecolor=black,
        colorlinks=true,
        hypertexnames=false,
        bookmarks=true,
        bookmarksnumbered=true,
        bookmarksopen=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

Testing. \cite{Shor:2010r}

\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\bibliography{testperiod}

\end{document}
```

Here's the .bib entry in `testperiod.bib`:

```
@UNPUBLISHED{Shor:2010r,
  author = {Boris Shor and Jon C. Rogowski},
  title = {Congressional Voting by Spatial Reasoning},
  month = {April},
  year = {2010},
  owner = {Boris},
  timestamp = {2010.07.01}
}
```

The generated bbl file is:

```
\harvarditem{Shor \harvardand\ Rogowski}{2010}{Shor:2010r}
Shor, Boris \harvardand\ Jon~C. Rogowski. 2010.
\newblock ``Congressional Voting by Spatial Reasoning.''.
```

And it comes out as:

Shor, Boris and Jon C. Rogowski. 2010. "Congressional Voting by Spatial Reasoning.".

The extra period afterward looks pretty ugly. Why is it there? And how to get rid of it?

Comment: Please give a complete, minimal example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. Can you tell me what would be more helpful in a little more detail?

Comment: Yes. Give a document that we can actually compile that produces the unwanted period. You didn't even tell us what bibliographystyle you're using. By the way, if you want someone to be notified that you responded to this, put their name after an @. So, @TH. to notify me. You got notified of that comment, and this one because they're comments on your question.

Comment: Thanks @TH. Live and learn. I'll put that document together. But how do I post it? It may be lengthy with the preamble and all.

Comment: It should be a **minimal** example. Approx. 10 lines of code should be enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @bshor: that' s where *minimal* in *minimal example* comes in: remove everything from the example which is not needed to show the effect you want to show.

Comment: I just added the minimal example that shows the problem in the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is hinted at in the BibTeX warning>

```
Warning--empty note in Shor:2010r
```

It's adding a period after the note field. Since the note field is empty, it just adds a period.

Admittedly, I too failed to heed the warning and had to look at aspr.bst to figure out what was going on.

Comment: Thanks @TH.! I do see that if I include a note, the period moves to the end of the note. But none of my citations have notes, for I don't need them. What should I do?

Comment: The unpublished entry type wants a note that says how the document is available... It's pointless citing something unless it's possible for people reading it to be able to go and look at that source...

Comment: @bshor: in fact this is also "hinted" at when you enter the information in JabRef: in the "Required Fields" pane for the "Unpublished" types, you see the fields Author, Title, Notes, and Bibtexkey. These are required fields specified by the BibTeX documentation.

Comment: Ahh. I do see the "requirement" of notes. But that requirement makes no sense! I have an unpublished paper with an author, title, and key. What do I need a note for?

Comment: @bshor The note should point out the status of the paper (and, as Seamus points out, where it's available if possible). "Submitted" or "Accepted to..." if it's in the pipeline to be published, "Available at..." if you've posted it to (e.g.) a personal web page. At the very least, you should put "Manuscript" or "Unpublished" in the notes field --- then the reader won't confuse it with a miscellaneous reference and go off on a wild goose chase looking for it.

Comment: @Ross Churchley -- ok, now I see the utility of the notes field. "Manuscript" is perfect as a miscellaneous description of unpublished papers. If I have an unpublished paper electronically available, I'd just use the electronic entry. Although, that has the exact same issue -- need for a note.

Comment: @Ross Churchley. Notes are ok for unpublished, but they don't solve the problem for "electronic" entries. Still that darned .". problem.

Comment: @bshor: I see you already accepted an answer, but I'd like to reiterate Seamus's comment. If a document is unpublished, then the note is used to inform the reader how the document can be accessed. For electronic entries (which isn't what you asked about in this question), then the note is most likely to be used for the "Accessed on <date>" entries in bibliographies. (I actually think those are sort of useless, but some styles require them.)

Answer (score 3):

It is a problem with your type of "unpublished". The style file inserts a period after a title and also after the complete bib entry. This is no problem when you also have a note entry, which will be typeset after the title. Use this [style file](http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/myapsr.bst) and it should work. Put it into your document directory or into your local TeX tree. For the latter don't forget to update the file name data base.

[image]

Comment: @Herbert I tried "techreport" but it inserts the text "Technical Report" at the end. No institution was entered. Argh!

Comment: techreport avoids the need for "notes" but adds the text "Technical Report" at the end of the cite. electronic only needs the key! But ... still that ugly .". !

Comment: then copy the `apsr.bst` to `myapsr.bst` and delete the line `fin.entry`  in the style file, update the database and use `\bibliographystyle{myapsr}`

Comment: Ok. Where's apsr.bst located? Can I place the replacement bst file in the directory where the paper is located?

Comment: @Herbert. I couldn't find the apsr.bst file but I downloaded the newest one from CTAN. I removed the "fin.entry" line from the "unpublished" definition, and while it removed the extraneous period, it removed the title, too!

Comment: @bshor: take this one, which works for me: http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/myapsr.bst` See edited answer

Comment: @Herbert: I see you've modified your answer to fix the bst file instead. So I've removed the (by now) irrelevant comments. Sorry for orphaning any comments.

Comment: @Herbert thanks for fixing the bst file. But your link is broken! :(

Comment: @bshor: should work now